# Reg. transaction support for a spring batch job at job level

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

Lets assume that i need to execute a spring batch job with 2 steps.step 1 is to read data from a postgres table and update values in the same table. step 2 is to read data from another postgres table and update this table. How can i achieve transactions at job level for this scenario?

That is, if the second step fails, then the first step should be rolled back.

Answer (score 1):

i'm not sure if there even exists an solution with automatic chained/multi-level transaction handling that works reliable (or does not need a lot resources on database side)

> if the second step fails, then the first step should be rolled back

well you could combine both steps into one:

- read from first table A
- use processor to update table A
- use processor to read from table B
- use writer to update table B

the performance will suffer a lot, because the read on table B will be a single read vs the cursor based for table a

i would go with a compensating strategy like this

- (optional) tables in use are temporary tables and not the real "production" tables, makes it easier to work with compensating with decoupling the datastores from the production
- a [failed step 1 triggers another step](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/reference/html/configureStep.html#programmaticFlowDecisions) or another job/script
- this step/job/script deletes as necessary (rows or complete table)

Comment: is it possible to have multiple tasklets or chunks inside a single step? if it is, then can we represent the above two tasks as 2 tasklets under a single step, which can be controlled by a transaction manager.

Comment: a Tasklet is a simplified Step and a Step is a domain object that encapsulates an independent, sequential phase of a batch job http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/reference/html/domain.html#domainStep

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using job-level transactionality?

[Job level Transactionality in Spring Batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12492176/job-level-transactionality-in-spring-batch)

*It's important to consider the potential volume size you are managing, in order to avoid out-of-the-limit commits or rollbacks*.

Answer (score -1):

Put a **BEGIN** statement before *Step 1* and a **COMMIT** statement after *Step 2*.

Comment: that is not how spring batch works with transaction, the transaction demarcation happens at unit of work level (aka commit-rate), steps are above this level