# Spring batch - Multiple step execution model, if step 3rd fails then data inserted by 1st and 2nd step should also get rolled back

Tags: postgresql, spring-batch

Is there a way to do this with CSV file.

I have multiple steps to execute on which each step is inserting data into the DB.

My scenario is if my 3rd step fails then step1 and step2 should also get failed or inserted data should get roll backed.

In my current design step1 and step2 successfully inserted data into DB even though my 3rd steps failed.

Comment: Do everything in a single transaction

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Job level Transactionality in Spring Batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12492176/job-level-transactionality-in-spring-batch)

Comment: I can't use single transaction model as each step committing data to a tables and tables are inter-dependent. For ex: step 1 inserts some in table then in step 3 I need to get some data from a column from step 1(i.e table 1)and insert into some column in step 3(i.e. table 3).